# uname -a doesn't show linux distribution version

Tags: linux

I try to know the linux distribution version of a remote linux machine. After trying several commands, I still can't identify the linux distribution version

```
$ uname -a
Linux server1 2.6.18 #1 Thu Jan 11 21:34:48 CET 2007 i686 athlon-4 i386 GNU/Linux

$ cat /proc/version
Linux version 2.6.18 (root@server1) (gcc version 3.4.6) #1 Thu Jan 11 21:34:48 CET 2007


$ cat /etc/issue
Welcome to \s \r (\l)

$ lsb_release -a
-sh: lsb_release: command not found

$ cat /etc/*-release
cat: /etc/*-release: No such file or directory
```

what can I do to know its linux distribution(i.e, redhat or debian or anything else?)

Comment: `lsb_release -a` or `cat /etc/issue`

Comment: @Bahamut they don't work

Comment: You may take a look at /etc/issue (if it has not been modified, it will normally have the OS name in it).

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz the link you provided can't solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

Try with it:

```
cat /etc/*-release
```

Comment: I tried, don't you see?

Comment: sorry, answer edited, try again

Comment: it doesn't work